# Layout changing(resizing) when switching from mobile to desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

The whole layout resizes when I change from desktop to mobile view. Elements with a width of 500px that should take up the entire screen don't.

I want mobile to look the same as desktop.

I've tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no/>` to every index.php, but nothing changed.

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbtT1.png)
[Moblie view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgMjP.png)

Comment: You're required to show your markup and CSS here. We can't help if we can't see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` to another index.php and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is missing some chars (commas, quotation marks). You can try if this works:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```